# Update texture of mesh using ThreeJS & Dat.Gui

Tags: reactjs, three.js, dat.gui

I would like the texture of my Mesh to update when clicked on function.

When you click on the 'UpdateMateria' function i'd like the mesh to dispose its current texture and add a new one.

[image: currentLook]

**Animation Loop**

```
  startAnimationLoop = () => {
   const tableBoard = this.scene.getObjectByName('tableSurface');
   tableBoard.material.map = this.updateMateria;

   this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
   this.requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimationLoop);
  };
```

**Dat.Gui**

```
  userGUI = () => {

    const update = {
      updateMateria: function() {
        alert('Changing');
        this.material.dispose();
        this.material.map = texture1();
      }
    }

    this.gui = new dat.GUI();
    const controls = function() {
    this.title = new controls();
    this.gui.add(update, 'updateMateria')
  }
}
```

When i put the function straight into the 'Animation Loop' this actually updates the texture to the desired one, but the current version gives me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can not use the `this` reference in `updateMateria` (probably `updateMaterial`???). Consider to safe the `this` reference in a variable outside of this function and use this variable instead. Besides, it's not necessary to dispose the material if you just want to change the texture.

```
userGUI = () => {

    const scope = this;

    const update = {
        updateMateria: function() {
            alert('Changing');
            // scope.material.dispose();
            scope.material.map = texture1();
        }
    }

    this.gui = new dat.GUI();
    const controls = function() {
    this.title = new controls();
    this.gui.add(update, 'updateMateria')

}
```

`three.js R108`